# How to Ignore a method attribute while running tests?

Tags: c#

My methods are decorated with the attribute

```
[TraceAspect]
public void Post()
 {
 }
```

I want to skip this attribute execution while running tests/calling the methods from a test project. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an additional method and call the method inside a method with attribute. So you can test method without attribute.

```
[TraceAspect]
public void Post()
{
    PostWithoutAttr();
}

public void PostWithoutAttr() 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I like this, only issue is PostWithoutAttr should only really be being called by the test code and its would be easy for it to 'infect' the system at large
with calls to it,  it also doesn't address 'deep calls'

Comment: This is a good solution, but only thing is my method is a controller and I am doing integration testing, so in that case I can't call the PostWithoutAttr() directly. But I will definetly keep this in mind for unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes aren't executable code. They're just metadata.

If the attribute "does" something, it's because the code is modified at compile-time based on the attributes. I assume you're using some Aspect framework like PostSharp that handle this for you. If you decompile your resulting DLL, you'll see that the attribute is gone, and the code of your method contains whatever code the aspect adds.

To find a way to avoid this, you'll have to consult the documentation of your aspect framework. However, it isn't a very good idea to test different code than what actually runs - you might want to look at alternate solutions, like redirecting the trace somewhere else or something like that.

There may be some ways to avoid this by using conditional compilation, though it's not going to work very well. For example, you could set a variable on your build server that avoids either the attribute itself (`#if !TESTING`), or the build task that handles the conversion from attribute to code. You could use different build configurations to have versions with and without the transformation. But really, all of those are quite ugly.

Comment: "If the attribute "does" something, it's because the code is modified at compile-time based on the attributes." => or, it is worth pointing out, because the attribute is examined at runtime via reflection.

Comment: @Luaan I am using PostSharp, of which I have inherited OnMethodBoundaryAspect of post sharp into my TraceAspect class and customised. Now I am using this Trace Aspcet class for trace logging in my controllers. While running tests, I don't need Trace logs, but I do need them in production.

Comment: @wintersolider Yeah, I expected something like that. The simplest solution would still be to just ignore the traces (e.g. configure your trace listener or whatever), and it will mean you're running production code rather than magical-almost-like-production-code.